# How to group by sub data in array helper map yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I have a two tables

Investment

```
 id_investment
 id_investment_type
 name
```

Investment Type

```
 investment_type
 id_investment_type
 name
```

i get a array using function

```
ArrayHelper::map(Investment::find()->where(['id_investment_type'=>[1,2,3]])->all,'id_investment','name','id_investment_type');
```

this return

```
1
  investmentOneOfTypeOne
  investmentTwoOfTypeOne
2
  investmentOneOfTypeTwo
  investmentTwoOfTypeTwo
```

I want to change the `id_investment_type` of the `groupby` by the name of the investment_type

exampl

```
Build
 Mounting Office
 investmenTwo
 ...
Devices
 invetmentOne
 BuyLaptop
 ...
```

I tried like below

```
ArrayHelper::map(Investment::find()->where(['id_investment_type'=>[1,2,3]])->all,'id_investment','name','id_investment_type.name');
```

but doesn't work.

Please someone know if it's possible to do that.

Thank you!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have in your Investment `model` this method:

```
/*
* return ActiveQuery
* id represent the investment type id column
* id_investment_type represent Investment table column which does have a value from 
* Investment Type table
*/
public function getInvestmentType()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(InvestmentType::className(), ['id' => 'id_investment_type']);
    }
```

Then you can build your map like this:

```
ArrayHelper::map(Investment::find()
    ->with(['investmentType'])
    ->where(['id_investment_type'=>[1,2,3]])
    ->all(),'id_investment','investment_type.name');
```

Which will return the result of:

```
1   Mounting Office
2   InvestmenTwo
```

Comment: I have the function and I built the map as you say,I have the function and built the map as you say, removing id_investment_type. and leaving only name.
But you forgot the groupBy and the result is  Mounting Office, Investment but I need to group them by type showing the type name instead of the id. Thanks for reply

Comment: Good, if my answer helped you to make it work , do not forget to check answered.

Comment: I managed to build the map like this, the problem is when I group them that I don't want to show the id